# Unable to set state of an element of an array which is contained in an array itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, loops, axios

I am receiving data from my backend which is an array that contains multiple arrays and these multiple arrays contain three elements [name, email, binary].

```
response.data.data.values = [Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]
```

&

```
Array(3) = ['Name1', '201851002@ra.ac.in', '0']
.
.
.
Array(3) = ['Name21', '201851023@ra.ac.in', '1']
```

Code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

function Attendance() {
  const [attedanceList, setAttedanceList] = useState([]);

  Axios.get("http://localhost:9000/attendance").then((response) => {
    setAttedanceList(response.data.data.values);
  });

  function changeValue(event) {
    let { name, value } = event.target;
    setAttedanceList([
      attedanceList.map((items) => {
        return (
          items[0] === name && [...attedanceList, [items[0], items[1], value]]
        );
      }),
    ]);
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(attedanceList);
  }

  function sendAllValues() {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:9000/attendance", { attedanceList });
  }

  return (
    <form>
      {attedanceList.map((val, index) => {
        if (index !== 0) {
          let present = "present" + index;
          let absent = "absent" + index;
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <div>
                {val[0]} {val[1]}
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id={present}
                  name={val[0]}
                  value="1"
                  checked={val[2] === "1"}
                  onChange={changeValue}
                />
                <label for={present}>Present</label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id={absent}
                  name={val[0]}
                  value="0"
                  checked={val[2] === "0"}
                  onChange={changeValue}
                />
                <label for={absent}>Absent</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }
      })}
      <button type="submit" onClick={sendAllValues}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

I need to save the state of Binary(0 or 1) as per the radio input from the user, which is the third element of the all `Array(3)`. But despite trying so many times, I am unable to set the state of any particular radio button and its **corresponding binary pressed in any random order**. How can I do it?

Comment: A bit off topic but may help... I personally would transform that data into an array of objects in the backend before sending it over data.map(e=>({name:e[0],email:e[1],binary:e[2]})). Considering that there will always be 3 items in each array and in the correct order ofcourse

Answer (score 0):

Since data fetching is asynchronous, you should do it as a side-effect. If you're using hooks, a popular approach is to employ the `useEffect` hook.

Relevant code snippet:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async() => {
    const response = await Axios.get("http://localhost:9000/attendance")
    setAttedanceList(response.data.data.values);
  };

  fetchData().catch((e) => setError(e.message));
}, []);
```